# Symfony 2 not seeing updated output from controller in Create Pages tutorial

Tags: php, http, symfony, url-routing, yaml

I am currently following the [Creating Pages in Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html#the-hello-symfony-page) tutorial but I seem to have some strange caching or routing issue with creating the new `AcmeHelloBundle`.

My Acme\HelloBundle `routing.yml` has this:

```
acme_hello_homepage:
    pattern:  /hi/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index }
```

..and as per the tutorial, my `HelloController` is setup as follows:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/HelloBundle/Controller/HelloController.php
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HelloController
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Heyo '.$name.'!</body></html>');
    }
}
```

However, when I view this in the browser at 
`http://www.dev.ayrshireminis.com/app_dev.php/hi/CRMPicco`

then I see

> Hello CRMPicco!

Is there some caching thing going on with the original Acme demo meaning my change to the output to say "Heyo" instead of "Hello" is not being found?

This is the output from a `router:debug`:

```
[craig@crmpicco dev_ayrshireminis]$ app/console router:debug | grep hi
 acme_hello_homepage      ANY    ANY    ANY  /hi/{name}

[craig@crmpicco dev_ayrshireminis]$ app/console router:debug acme_hello_homepage
[router] Route "acme_hello_homepage"
Name         acme_hello_homepage
Path         /hi/{name}
Host         ANY
Scheme       ANY
Method       ANY
Class        Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
Defaults     _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index
Requirements
Options      compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
Path-Regex   #^/hi/(?P<name>[^/]++)$#s
```

Comment: Did you create a new AcmeHelloBundle? I think Symfony2 by default already has an AcmeHelloBundle, and that bundle might be getting routed before yours. Not sure if this is your problem though

Comment: app/console router:debug | grep hi

Comment: @LCH Yes, I created the `AcmeHelloBundle` from the SF2 tutorial. SF2 comes with the `AcmeDemoBundle` which does something very similar, and yes I think the first bundle is being routed before mine. I have renamed the original one though, so i'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @coma I have updated the question with the output from a `router:debug`. Why would the old DemoBundle be routed before mine? Do you think that is what is happening? I should have pointed out that I am a newbie with SF2, but I am very comfortable with PHP in general.

Comment: @crmpicco, it seems that you have a permission's issue; you have to give write access to app/cache and app/logs for the user running PHP and for your user (to use composer, change files and so). read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html and update your question.

Comment: @coma Yes, I did have a permissions issue on my `annotations` directory. I have made this writeable, and the router command now shows output with no error. So would this suggest my routing is ok? I am still seeing output from the old "Hello" script.

Comment: Great! now try app/console router:debug acme_hello_homepage

Comment: @coma Yep, i've done that and updated the question. This all points to the correct places from what I understanding. Why am I still seeing "Hello" instead of what I have in my code?

Comment: @crmpicco, what happened?

Comment: @coma Accepted answer and explanation below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `router:debug` you can see it pointing to *AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index*, and that's Acme\HelloBundle\ **Default** Controller::indexAction (src/Acme/HelloBundle/ **Default** Controller.php).

Maybe it's defined in app/config/routing_dev.yml.

Comment: Many thanks, this pointed me to the problem. I just had to change it to point to `AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index`, instead of `AcmeHelloBundle:Default:index`. So it was, as expected, a routing issue.

Comment: Great!, the console can be very handy.